# Jenkins Terminal does not support executing hg purge

Tags: jenkins, mercurial, jenkins-pipeline, purge

I am using jenkins, when executing `Hg purge --all -R D:\path` in jenkins pipeline it will return `hg: unknown command 'purge'.`

But when executing the same command in Windows Terminal it will execute correctly

Note : Jenkins in the same machine the Mercurial exist and `purge plugin`  exist in the big repo and and sub repo

How to solve that issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the rights on delirium:

- You may have more than one Mercurial on your host and Jenkins [configured](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Mercurial+Plugin) to use another instance (without extension), than command-prompt
- You run Jenkins under different user and different mercurial.ini used, without extension (per-repository config can't be read)

You can (select any method):

- enable extension on system-wide basis (and disable it in repositories, there you don't want it)
- replace extension by "old-style" [mercurial alias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19822916/960558)
- [forcibly enable extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1212486/960558) for single command `hg purge --config extensions.purge=`

From my POV, system-wide extension in mercurial.ini will be most easy and logical solution

Comment: can you share with me your knowledge in that question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56515835/mercurial-plugin-config-panel-not-shown-for-manage-jenkins-configure-system 
Regarding to that question