# Mercurial plugin config panel not shown for Manage Jenkins -> Configure System

Tags: jenkins, mercurial

I am using Jenkins, I a trying to configure Mercurial inside Jenkins.

But I can not find Mercurial section inside `Configure System`, to configure Mercurial Paths in Jenkins.

Is their any solution ?

Comment: According to [docs](https://plugins.jenkins.io/mercurial), you have to install plugin before configure - 
"Main Configuration, Step by Step:
1/ **Install the Jenkins Mercurial Plugin.**
2/ Under "Manage Jenkins", "Configure System", find the "Mercurial" section and add your Mercurial instance"

Comment: I already installed Mercurial plugin, but it's section under Configure System not found

Answer (score 1):

I found it under `Manage Jenkins=>Global Tool Configuration`